# Error max, min array PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me trae un array, a este array necesito sacarle el maximo, minimo y desviacion standar.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_pml);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_pml_mtr);
    $pml_mda = $pml_mtr = [];

while ($rorigen=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $pml_mda[] = $rorigen['pml_mda'] / $moneda;

while ($rdestino = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) $pml_mtr[] = $rdestino['pml_mtr'] / $moneda;
      
foreach ($pml_mda as $clave => $valor) {
    $diferencia = $valor - $pml_mtr[$clave];
    $dart = $diferencia.',';
    $dart_fix =substr($dart, 0, -1);
    $dart_fix;
    }
```

Si le hago `echo` a `$dart_fix` me trae los valores correctos en el string

> 3.21212.73205.11324.05279.05194.0493.8348.95-4.95-36.178.59198.94161.13302.44184.31248.23175.88263.2241.2208.28314.33208.88114.67128.84

A estos valores necesito sacar el maximo, minimo y stddev.
Al poner

> `echo max(dart_fix);`
> `echo min(dart_fix);`

no me manda nada.

**EDIT:**
Se hacen dos querys por que necesito obtener la diferencia entre estos dos campos que son de distintas tablas.
Debo obtener una tabla donde muestre esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer query me trae los datos MDA(AVG,MAX,MIN,STDDEV)

El segundo query me trae los datos MTR(AVG,MAX,MIN,STDDEV)

Mi falta de habilidad y conocimiento me hicieron pensar a solamente le resto uno al otro y sera correcto. Pero en realidad necesito obtener tambien
(AVG,MAX,MIN,STDDEV)
de la diferencia de los dos querys.

Comment: Hola. ¿Por qué haces dos consultas y no una? Aclara también si necesitas todos los demás valores para algo, pues de necesitar sólo el `max` y el `min` los puedes traer ya desde la consulta SQL, haciendo además una sola consulta.

Comment: Hola, edito la pregunta.

Comment: Prueba ```$dart = []; foreach ($pml_mda as $clave => $valor) { $diferencia = $valor - $pml_mtr[$clave]; $dart[] = $diferencia;}``` y fuera del **foreach** haces esto para obtener ```$max_value = max($dart); echo $max_value```

Comment: no sé como tendrás tus datos, o si puedes mostrarnos un poco de la estructura de la tabla y algunos datos aleatorios, pero para mí que esto se resuelve directamente en la consulta SQL, allí puede agrupar por Origen, y quitas el max, el min y la desviacion standard utilizando las propias funciones nativas de la base.

Comment: Correcto quedo correcto, ahora solo me falta sacar el max y min de mda y mtr y juntarlos todos

Comment: ¿Con juntarlos todos a que te refieres? Respecto a sacar el *mda* y *mtr* puedes hacer lo mismo, recuerda cuando recorres tu *while* creas un array ```$pml_mda[] = ..``` entonces simplemente puedes obtener el max o min y después ya creas tus cálculos, algo como ```$max_mda_mtr = max($pml_mda) + max($pml_mtr);```..etc

Comment: Si es correcto lo hice y funciono, ahora tengo un problema jajaaj como saco la desviacion estandar?

Comment: Si te refieres a el promedio lo podrías calcular de la siguiente manera: ```$promedio_pml_mda = array_sum($pml_mda) / count($pml_mda);```, aquí tienes más ejemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434648/z-scoresstandard-deviation-and-mean-in-php